# How to convert Vec<Item> to Vec<String>?

Tags: vector, rust, visibility, private, map-function

I have the following object, and trying to convert `Vec<Courses>` and retrieve `CourseName`.

```
pub struct Schools {
    pub courses: Vec<CourseName>,
}

pub struct CourseName(String);

impl CourseName {
    pub fn as_str(&self) -> &str {
        &self.0[..]
    }
}
```

Trying to get the `Vec<String>`, but my following approach does not work,

```
assigned_courses:Vec<String> = courses.iter().map(|c| c.clone().as_str()).collect()
```

getting the following error:

```
value of type `Vec<std::string::String>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str>`
```

Update:

[image]

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `map` closure receives a `&CourseName` so `clone` just copies the reference. What you instead want is to access the tuple and clone the inner `String` with `c.0`.

```rust
let assigned_courses: Vec<String> = courses.iter().map(|c| c.0.clone()).collect();
```

Alternatively, if references to the course names are enough, then instead you can use `as_str` on the inner String.

```rust
let assigned_courses: Vec<&str> = schools.courses.iter().map(|c| c.0.as_str()).collect();
```

---

To fix the "private field" error. You can add a visibility modifier, e.g.

```rust
pub struct CourseName(pub String);
```

However, it's probably better to keep it as private, and instead add a method like `as_str()`.

```rust
impl CourseName {
    pub fn as_str(&self) -> &str {
        &self.0
    }
}
```

Then resulting in:

```rust
let assigned_courses: Vec<String> = schools.courses.iter().map(|c| c.as_str().to_string()).collect();
```

Alternatively, you could also impl [`AsRef<str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) and/or [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) for `CourseName`, to make everything more generalized.

---

Assuming that `CourseName` is just to have a typed version instead of a `String`. Then you could instead impl [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) for `CourseName`.

```rust
use std::fmt;

pub struct CourseName(String);

impl fmt::Display for CourseName {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.0)
    }
}
```

This allows you to do `println!("{}, course")` along with `course.to_string()`.

```rust
let assigned_courses: Vec<String> = schools.courses.iter().map(|c| c.to_string()).collect();
```

Comment: I am getting `value of type `Vec<std::string::String>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str>`

Comment: Note that I added `.0` and removed `as_str()`

Comment: I have got an issue, updated my question accordingly.

Comment: I have updated my question accordingly, actually I have the `as_str()` method but it is slightly different, how could I able to handle with your solution. Sorry, I am newbie to the Rust, still learning.

Comment: Unsure what you mean? You can simplify your `&self.0[..]` into `&self.0`. But if you mean why yours didn't work. Them notice that I wrote `as_str` then `clone` and not vice versa, which you originally did.

Comment: is it possible to keep `&self.0[...]`, because I am afraid to break other things.

Comment: You can keep it. In this context the result of `&self.0[..]` and `&self.0` is the same.

Comment: If I do not make any changes to &self.0[...], then I am getting the following error: value of type `Vec<std::string::String>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225545/discussion-between-vallentin-and-casillas).

Comment: @vallentin thanks million of times for helping someone who is learning Rust. I really appreciate your effort and time. You have not only helped me, you also taught me cool tricks. I wish I could able to give more upvotes! Have a wonderful weekend!

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct CourseName(pub String);

fn courses_to_strings(list: &[CourseName]) -> Vec<String> {
    list.iter().map(|course| course.0.clone()).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let courses: Vec<CourseName> = vec![
        CourseName("a".to_string()),
        CourseName("b".to_string())
    ];
    let strings = courses_to_strings(&courses);
    dbg!(strings);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e30f032e9e5f55dd85de0594f4e7a4d)

All you needed to do was `clone` the `String` instead of the `CourseName` tuple struct in your `map` function, and also add the `pub` visibility modifier to the internal `String`.

Comment: Getting the following error ` value of type `Vec<std::string::String>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str>`

Comment: Did you go to the playground link and run the code? It compiles and runs fine.